# Определить существование файла по названию не зная его расширения

Tags: php

```
// листинг файлов в виде массива
$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/pics', 1);

/*
содержимое массива $files

Array
(
    [0] => 9.jpg
    [1] => 8.gif
    [2] => 7.jpg
    [3] => 6.gif
    [4] => 5.jpg
    [5] => 4.jpg
    [6] => 3.jpg
    [7] => 2.gif
    [8] => 12.jpg
    [9] => 11.jpg
    [10] => 10.jpg
    [11] => 1.gif
    [12] => ..
    [13] => .
)
*/
```

Как определить что в каталоге `/images/pics` существует файл с названием `11` ?
* расширения неизвестны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr=glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/pics/11.*');
if(count($arr)>0) {
   echo "Файлы присутствуют ...";
   var_dump($arr);
 }
```